# Implementing API authentication by requiring API Key present on request header using Rust actix-web

Tags: api, authentication, rust, middleware, actix-web

I am working on a very basic API using actix-web to set-up my web server. The API has two protected endpoints that require authorization and a public health-check endpoint. I am attempting to check the request header for a valid API-KEY that matches with the database to authorize access to the protected endpoints.

I am looking for help in adding a simple actix-web middleware at the Scope level, so that it applies to all my protected routes. Despite trying different approaches, I have been unsuccessful in making the middleware work.

**main.rs**

```
*** Code above here is not important ***

    let main_db_pool = Arc::new(client);
    let bind_addr = &env::var("BIND_ADDR").unwrap_or_else(|_| "localhost:8080".to_owned());
    log::info!(" Server started successfully! Listening on {:?}", bind_addr.clone());
    let http_server = HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new()
            .app_data(actix_web::web::Data::new(AppState {
                db_pool: main_db_pool.clone(),
            }))
            .service(routes::health_check_handler) // Need to understand why this handler need to come first before the routes below, otherwise not working.
            .service(routes::protected_routes())
    });
    // Check if we're running locally for development and testing
    if env::var("ENVIRONMENT").unwrap_or_else(|_| "development".to_owned()) == "development" {
        // Use Self-Signed Certificate. This will change to bind_openssl or bind_rustls
        http_server.bind(bind_addr)?.run().await
    } else {
        // Use the default HTTPS provided by the cloud provider
        http_server.bind(bind_addr)?.run().await
    }
```

**routes.rs**

```
use crate::account_resource_handlers::{get_account_by_id_handler, insert_account_handler};
use serde::Serialize;
use actix_web::{web, get, Responder, HttpResponse};

pub fn protected_routes() -> actix_web::Scope {
    web::scope("/api")
        **// .wrap(api_key_validation_middleware)** **This is where I want to add middleware if possible cause I believe if here, it will apply to all routes below.**
        .service(web::resource("/accounts").route(web::post().to(insert_account_handler)))
        .service(web::resource("/accounts/{id}").route(web::get().to(get_account_by_id_handler)))
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct HealthCheckResponse {
    pub status: String,
    pub message: String,
}

// Apply rate limiter in this resource endpoint to prevent abuse. How?
#[get("/api/healthcheck")]
pub async fn health_check_handler() -> impl Responder {
    let response_json = &HealthCheckResponse {
        status: "success".to_string(),
        message: "API is running!".to_string(),
    };
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(response_json)
}
```

**UPDATE:** With the help of @Jonas, my code is now compiling. Here is the new version of **routes.rs**

```
use crate::account_resource_handlers::{get_account_by_id_handler, insert_account_handler};
use actix_web::{
    dev::{Service, ServiceFactory, ServiceRequest, ServiceResponse},
    get, web, HttpResponse, Responder,
};
use futures_util::future::ready;
use serde::Serialize;

pub fn protected_routes() -> actix_web::Scope<
    impl ServiceFactory<
        ServiceRequest,
        Config = (),
        Response = ServiceResponse,
        Error = actix_web::Error,
        InitError = (),
    >,
> {
    web::scope("/api")
        .wrap_fn(|req, srv| match req.headers().get("X-API-Key") {
            Some(_) => srv.call(req),
            None => Box::pin(ready(Ok(ServiceResponse::new(
                req.into_parts().0,
                HttpResponse::Unauthorized().finish(),
            )))),
        })
        .service(web::resource("/accounts").route(web::post().to(insert_account_handler)))
        .service(web::resource("/accounts/{id}").route(web::get().to(get_account_by_id_handler)))
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct HealthCheckResponse {
    pub status: String,
    pub message: String,
}

// Apply rate limiter in this resource endpoint to prevent abuse. How?
#[get("/api/healthcheck")]
pub async fn health_check_handler() -> impl Responder {
    let response_json = &HealthCheckResponse {
        status: "success".to_string(),
        message: "API is running!".to_string(),
    };
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(response_json)
}
```

Comment: Your reasoning of calling `Scope::wrap` or `Scope::wrap_fn` on your protected routes is correct. Have you read the [documentation](https://actix.rs/docs/middleware) on middlewares? Also interesting are the API docs for [`App::wrap_fn`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.App.html#method.wrap_fn) and [`App::wrap`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/struct.App.html#method.wrap). I'd recommend starting with a simple `wrap_fn`, extract the API key from the request, look it up in the database and authorize accordingly.

Comment: Exactly what I'm doing and I am stuck. I put it inline to make more simpler:
```
pub fn protected_routes() -> actix_web::Scope {
    web::scope("/api")
        .wrap_fn(|req, srv| {
            match req.headers().get("X-API-Key") {
                Some(api_key) => srv.call(req),
                None => Ok(HttpResponse::Unauthorized().finish()),
            }
        })
        .service(web::resource("/accounts").route(web::post().to(insert_account_handler)))
        .service(web::resource("/accounts/{id}").route(web::get().to(get_account_by_id_handler)))
}
```
This not compile.

Comment: Could you please add that information to your question? It'd make it a lot easier to help you. Your middleware function is not working because of a simple type mismatch in your match arms. [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7e748a77b9b5dbe5dacc3ea8c3c14b01) is a version of your middleware function that compiles.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was not really in my code. The one that I'm trying out is not an inline middleware and it's messy. I just create the inline to simplify my problem. Now it's compiling! I'll update my post above to put the working version of the inline version. My next task here is to move out the inline function and implement the actual checking of api-key from the database. But this is outside anymore of my original post if I will encounter another problem.